# Error when configuring Datasource Oracle 11g into Apache Tomcat 7 (7.0.82)

Tags: java, oracle11g, tomcat7, datasource, ojdbc

I am trying to change the configuration in my application to use the datasource into the Apache Tomcat server with Oracle DB 11g, but it is throwing an error about SYS.AUD$ tablespace. Follow my configuration:

*$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/**context.xml***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

<Resource auth="Container" 
         name="jdbc/oracleds"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME"
         username="${db.user}" 
         password="${db.password}" 
         maxActive="20"
         maxIdle="10" 
         maxWait="10000"       
         validationQuery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"
       />

</Context>
```

While the server is loading the following exception is displayed into the console:

```
Jul 24, 2018 11:17:37 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of the pool.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 1024 in tablespace SYSTEM
ORA-02002: error while writing to audit trail
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 1024 in tablespace SYSTEM

       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:156)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:245)
       at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:333)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:751)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:694)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` with `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: I've already tried this solution, but I keep getting the same error. In fact, as explained in another topic here in StackOverflow, this driver class should be avoided: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes)

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED** I've discovered that my **database FREE SPACE was very low (less than 100 MB)** so I've asked the support team to fix it (increasing the memory available) and now the initial configuration has worked as expected.

Giving a look at another resolved question here I've found some interesting information about how to configure the Connection Pool in Tomcat server:

[org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ( 'v$session.osuser' , value is 'x')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624128/org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-sqlnestedexception-cannot-create-poolableconnection)